# How to format ListBox selection as Accounting Value in excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a ListBox that populates based on a keyword search. After I make a selection I am able to populate an excel sheet with the columns of data that are in the ListBox. However, the numeric values populate in a "Currency" number format rather than "Accounting".

The ListBox is populated from a database excel sheet where all values are in "Accounting" format. A generic number format is shown in the ListBox. And as previously mentioned, the sheet to populate with the ListBox selection changes the numbers to "Currency".

The code below shows the values from the database sheet that would be transferred over to the new excel once the selection is made in the ListBox.

```
ListRow = lstKitResult.ListIndex + 3
Cells(Num, 2).Value = Worksheets("Kit_database").Cells(ListRow, 2).Value
Cells(Num, 3).Value = Worksheets("Kit_database").Cells(ListRow, 3).Value
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to format numbers in listbox. How do you load data to listbox ? If with .Additem method, then you may use e.g. ListBox1.AddItem Format(mynumber, "000 000.00") and setting format whatever you want.

Comment: I don't believe I am using the .AddItem method. `If LCase(Mid(Sheet8.Cells(i, 3), x, a)) = Me.txtKitKeyword And Me.txtKitKeyword <> "" Then
    Me.lstKitResult.AddItem Sheet8.Cells(i, 3)
    Me.lstKitResult.List(lstKitResult.ListCount - 1, 1) = "" & Sheet8.Cells(i, 2)
    Me.lstKitResult.List(lstKitResult.ListCount - 1, 2) = "" & Sheet8.Cells(i, 4)
    Me.lstKitResult.List(lstKitResult.ListCount - 1, 3) = "" & Sheet8.Cells(i, 5)` This is the code that is pulling data and adding it to the ListBox.

Comment: Look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) it's more info about Format function